# How to make sure that a user has a premium account on a freemium platform?

Tags: linkedin-api, spotify, verification

Is there a simple way to make verify that a user has a premium account on a freemium platform like LinkedIn for instance (but it could be Spotify or any other service) ?

I understand that the user will have to give me an access to his account but is there an API to do that or do I have to do it in an other way ?

If there is no API, I imagined a technique (which is dirty for sure) :

- The user give me his credentials on the service to check
- The system would then connect to his account and download a premium specific page
- Then, parse this page to look for premium feature.
- If the premium feature is found, then it's a premium account, if not, then it's not a premium account.

However, in my opinion, this is a very dirty way to do that.

Do you have any suggestion to make it better or do you know if most freemium services have an API to check this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Spotify's Web API enables any web application request users' permission to see their "product status".

This is an example of the out you'd get if the user 'wizzler' allowed an application to see his private information.

```
{
  "country": "SE",
  "display_name": "JM Wizzler",
  "email": "email@example.com",
  "external_urls": {
    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/user/wizzler"
  },
  "followers" : {
    "href" : null,
    "total" : 3829
  },
  "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler",
  "id": "wizzler",
  "images": [
    {
      "height": null,
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc3/t1.0-1/1970403_10152215092574354_1798272330_n.jpg",
      "width": null
    }
  ],
  "product": "premium",
  "type": "user",
  "uri": "spotify:user:wizzler"
}
```

As you see, the "product" property contains "premium". The only other possible value is "free".

[Try it out using Spotify's Web API Console](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-current-user/). (Be sure to select the **user-read-private** scope)

Documentation: [Get Current User's Profile](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/)